# How can I include the "source" field from the Microsoft Azure Custom Question Answer API?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, nlp, azure-machine-learning-service, nlp-question-answering

I am leveraging the latest iteration of Azure's Custom question answering module in language studio in an external app that I've created, and I cannot figure out how to receive the actual source when the question is answered. I don't know if that's because you just can't right now or what, but in the actual API docs for the request/answer sample, the answer sample includes the source field - no matter what I've tried, I can't get it to show up.
Page where API doc is found - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/questionanswering/question-answering/get-answers#knowledgebaseanswer

Quick example snippet of how I've adapted the API:

```js
{
  "question": "<question>",
  "top": 3,
  "userId": "<user>",
  "confidenceScoreThreshold": 0.2,
  "rankerType": "Default",
  "filters": {
    "metadataFilter": {
      "metadata": [
        
      ],
    },
  },
  "answerSpanRequest": {
    "enable": true,
    "confidenceScoreThreshold": 0.2,
    "topAnswersWithSpan": 1
  },
  
  },
  "includeUnstructuredSources": true
}
```

I understand the metadata bit has nothing there, I may add something later but as of now I'm not messing with the metadata aspect in language studio sources themselves.

At any rate, the bottom line is I don't see an option to display a source, and I don't get it back in the body of the request - yet I see it in the sample response in the API doc, so what gives, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you still workin on this? I am in a project myself and in my environment, the source is part of the result.